# Ggplot2, adding geom_text with several lines in faceted plot, without superimposition

Tags: r, ggplot2, counting, facet, geom-text

I have a dataset which has the following structure :

```
dat <- data.frame(value = sample(0:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
                  struct = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 5),
                  category = rep(letters[1:5], 4))
```

And I want to plot a histogram showing the count of each `value` for each `category`, faceted by `struct`, as follows :

```
plot <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = value, y = ..count..)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, alpha = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), aes(color = category, fill = category)) +
  facet_wrap(~ struct)
```

My problem is that I would like to add the number of observations used for **each** category of **each** facet, as this number can vary, because I have to deal with incomplete data.
Technically, one easy way to deal with the problem is adding something like :

```
plot +
geom_text(data=plyr::count(dat, vars = c("struct", "category")), aes(x=5, y = 10, label= paste0("n =", freq)), colour = 'black', size = 4, inherit.aes=FALSE, parse=FALSE)
```

But doing this yields two problems :

1. in each facet, all texts are superimposed on each other.
2. I cannot distinguish which number relates to which category.

I know that the problem with 1) is that I put fixed coordinates for the text, and I would need to have at least a flexible **y** coordinate so that each text can be on a different line, but I cannot, for the life of me, find a way to do this. It always results in an error which says that *"Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): y"* ... I'm pretty sure that this is an extremely stupid problem, but I've been trying for hours and can't seem to find a somewhat clean solution.

As for 2), the easy way would be to color each text with the color of the corresponding category, but this doesn't work, as the data argument passed into `geom_text` is not my regular dataset, but a count function on the dataset.

Is there any way to fix these problems ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall the easiest approach would be to compute the counts for your labels outside of `ggplot2` for which I use `dplyr::count`. To deal with the issue of the `y` position for the labels I use `position_stack` so that the labels are stacked on top of each other. However, doing so requires a value for `y` for which I have chosen the max count divided by the number of categories. Finally I placed the labels on the right of the histograms by setting `x = 6`.

Note: I slightly adjusted your example data.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

n <- 40
dat <- data.frame(
  value = sample(0:5, n, replace = TRUE),
  struct = sample(LETTERS[1:4], n, replace = TRUE),
  category = sample(letters[1:5], n, replace = TRUE)
)

dat_label <- dat |>
  dplyr::count(struct, category)

y_max <- dat |>
  count(struct, category, cut_width(value, width = 1)) |> 
  pull(n) |> 
  max()

ggplot(dat, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(
    binwidth = 1, alpha = 0.5,
    position = position_dodge(width = .8), aes(color = category, fill = category)
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = dat_label,
    aes(
      x = 6,
      y = y_max / 5, # 5 = number of categories
      label = paste0("n = ", n), color = category
    ),
    position = position_stack(),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~struct)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after_stat` function, without having to use external functions such as `plyr::count`

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(color = category, fill = category),
    binwidth = 1,
    alpha = 0.5,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
    
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(color = category, label = after_stat(count)),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    vjust = 'outward',
    stat = 'count',
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ struct)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you ! The problem with this solution is that it gives me the number of observations for each value of each category within a facet, whereas I'm looking for the total number of observations for each category within each facet irrelevant of the values.  So I'm looking for the sum of what your solution gives me... But using ```after_stat(sum(count))``` for some reason goes back to the sum of ALL observations in the dataset...